# Como puedo asignarles recursos "productos" de mi empresa a mi trabajador sin tener relacionada la tabla productos y trabajador

Tags: base-de-datos, modelorelacional

estoy tratando de que mi cliente se le puedan asignar los recursos que han sido comprados por la empresa, pero no puedo llegar a la solución ya que nose si podria tener una tabla que guarde todos mis productos o algo por el estilo dado que cliente no tiene relacion con la tabla productos nose como podría implementarlo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
, mi logica me dice que tengo que relacionarlo con la tabla productos pero esos productos aun no son de mi empresa asi que nose como podria hacerlo, ¿no es necesario relacionar alguna tabla?

Comment: Porqué no usas otra tabla para relacionar productos y clientes?

Comment: Cuando dices *“... no son de mi empresa ...”*, ¿lo dices como cliente o como proveedor?.

Comment: lo digo como cliente

Comment: como podria ussa otra tabla?

Comment: La relación existe, es indirecta a través de la orden de compra. A menos que los productos no sean comprados (ej. prestados) crearías otra tabla que podrías relacionar con Cliente, Obra o Empresa.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo de la imagen que agregaste, ya tienes una tabla que va a almacenar todos los productos, si quieres asignárselos al cliente tienes que agregarle la clave principal del producto (en este caso el product ID o como lo tengas declarado) como clave foránea a tu tabla de clientes, ahí debería lograrse.
También tienes que evaluar bien tu base de datos relacional entre los productos y los clientes, en mi experiencia la relación productos - clientes sería de muchos a muchos.
Si no es lo que estás buscando, deberías reformular mejor tu pregunta con la intención de entender bien lo que quieres lograr.